# NoClassDefFoundError With Google Wallet and new Google Play Services 6.5.87

Tags: google-play-services, android-pay

After updating to use the new modularized Google Play Services I get the following error when trying to run my app.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$style;
            at com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.WalletFragmentStyle.ab(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.WalletFragmentOptions.ab(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my gradle dependency

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:6.5.87"
```

Looks like Google Wallet is trying to reference com.google.android.gms.R.style when it's style class is generated in com.google.android.gms.wallet.R.style.  Is there any way to fix this without and update to the Play Services SDK?

Comment: Can you please show us how you initializing WalletFragmentStyle?

Comment: Looks like I can't reproduce this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

"Has nothing to do with mavenCentral, you need to make sure you have the latest SDK packages installed for "Google Repository" and "Google Play services"

This was already answered here: [answered by Sam Dozor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390156/modular-play-services-not-working-in-gradle)

i tired it and works great!

Comment: This is a different issue.  I don't have any issues getting the correct dependency.  I get a crash at runtime because when I use the modularized play services version of google wallet it is expecting the generated R.style class to be in com.google.android.gms.R.style when it is actually being generated as com.google.android.gms.wallet.R.style.