# modular Play Services not working in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

So Google has released modular Play Services and supposedly you can do something like this in your gradle file:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+'

but I get an error saying:
Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+

I'm on Android Studio 1.0 (rels. 12/8/2014) w/ the latest version of gradle.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: they are using jcenter now ... also did you download newest m2repository?

Comment: Does `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'` also not work for you?

Comment: @ianhanniballake try the answer by Sam, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has nothing to do with `mavenCentral`, you need to make sure you have the latest SDK packages installed for "Google Repository" and "Google Play services"

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

[image]